# Create a new chart for each new page

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a JSON ([SurveyJS](https://surveyjs.io/)) with the responses from users:

```
var surveyJSON = {pages:[{name:"page1",elements:[{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you conducting market analysis?",description:"5 - most confident"},{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you evaluating the feasibility of a new opportunity?",description:"5 - most confident"},{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you discovering new ways to improve existing products?",description:"5 - most confident"}]},{name:"page2",elements:[{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you targeting new markets and customers?",description:"5 - most confident",isRequired:true},{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you reacting quickly to take advantage of business opportunities?",description:"5 - most confident",isRequired:true},{type:"rating",name:"How confident are you creating new products and services and/or developing new ideas?",description:"5 - most confident"}]}]}
```

And I'm trying to generate a new chart for each new page of responses with my HighChart. So, Page 1 has Chart 1, Page 2 has Chart 2, etc...
The catch? I don't necessarily know how many pages the JSON has.

How will I come about something like this?

My current HighCharts code which takes all responses (not what I want):

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Your confidence levels'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: titleArray,
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Your confidence levels',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: valuesArray
    }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get `surveyJSON.pages.length` or if you have access to your surveyjs model you can get `survey.pages.length` ?